# Should RightToLeft be applied just to text or to image as well?

Tags: controls, windows-os, winforms

I have developed a control in which an image and text is displayed.

In left-to-right mode, the text is located on the left and the image on right side of control:

[image]

I have provided support for right-to-left display for my control, applying it just to the text, though, so currently it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to know if I should **switch the position of the image and text as well**, so that the text is displayed on the left in RTL mode:

[image]

> *Editor note: This question has been heavily edited, however I believe I have decoded the intent correctly. The author of this question included this version of the control as well:*
>   [image]
>   *However, it is not clear to me what the original intent for this version was.*

Comment: Could you provide some screenshot?

Comment: @DominikOslizlo , JonW - see the edits with images.

Comment: It's still not very clear what you're asking. Are you asking 'if an image is on the right, should the text be right-aligned?'

Comment: I have options for Image and Text alignment. ImageBeforeText, ImageAfterText as you can see from images. When RTL is enabled, do i have to draw image after text when ImageBeforeText is set and vice versa? Or just changing the RTL drawing for only text?

Comment: @Amal, could you tell me if the question - in the way it is after I edited it - does convey what you wanted to ask about?

Comment: @DominikOslizlo - Thanks for the edit. You have conveyed perfectly. Only in last image, the text is drawn in right to image but stringformatflags for the text is not set with RightToLeft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It totally depends on what you want the user to see first.**

because LTR mode is for normal people who read starting from left and end at right so main thing which has to be shown should be on left.

and RTL mode is for people like in ARAB countries where people do their reading starting from right and at left.

if you want the image to be seen first followed by text.

1. then in LTR do

[image]

1. in RTL

[image]

and do it accordingly if you want text to be shown first